# layout:decorate don't work - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a Java Spring Boot project with thymeleaf. I tried to use layout:decorate wihout success with a lot of web examples. The last one is that:

The index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
     layout:decorate="~{Layout}">
<head>
  <title>Content page 1</title>
  <script src="content-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section layout:fragment="content">
    <p>This is a paragraph from content page 1</p>
  </section>
  <footer>
<p layout:fragment="custom-footer">This is some footer content from content     page 1</p>
  </footer>
  <a th:href="@{/Layout}">Teste</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
  <title>Layout page</title>
  <script src="common-script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My website</h1>
  </header>
  <section layout:fragment="content">
    <p>Page content goes here</p>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <p>My footer</p>
    <p layout:fragment="custom-footer">Custom footer here</p>
  </footer>  
</body>
</html>
```

The pom.xml parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

The pom.xml properties:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>8</java.version>

    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.2</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
</properties>
```

I don't know whats happen :(

Thank you!

Comment: What did you get, and what did you expect to get?

Comment: layout:decorate="~{Layout}", 

The layout.html file has the header and footer of my page. In this page that I posted, there is only the content.

I want this page to recognize the layout.html and bring the header and footer. When I run my program, opening the page loads it (only content). It looks like you can not find the layout.html.

Comment: Same problem. My solution: downgrade thymeleaf 3 to 2 and spring boot 2 to 1.